# Зачем нужны вложенные блоки синхронизации?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем здесь использованы вложенные блоки синхронизации? И почему бы просто не добавить `synchronized` в сигнатуру метода? Разницу, точнее, я понимаю: в одном случае синхронизация по одному объекту, во втором - сразу по двум, но зачем? Вроде где-то что-то нашла про то, что таким образом пытаются избежать deadlock, но абсолютно не понимаю как это работает.

```
public void transfer(Account source, Account target, double amount) {
    synchronized (sourceLock) {
        synchronized (targetLock) {
            source.setBalance(source.getBalance() - amount);
            target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не понятно, откуда берутся объекты `sourceLock` и `targetLock`.

Если это просто два глобальных статических объекта, то никакой разницы между блокировкой на методе и тем, как написано.

А вот если они как-то вычисляются в зависимости от счетов `source` и `target`, тогда разница есть и скорее всего код содержит ошибку, как указали в комментариях.

> И почему бы просто не добавить synchronized в сигнатуру метода?

В таком случае банк сможет проводить только одну транзакцию в момент времени, даже если счета не связаны между собой

`A->B` и `C->D` не могут проводиться одновременно, потому что лок на методе.

> во втором - сразу по двум, но зачем?

В том виде, как написано сейчас, `A->B` и `C->D` могут проводиться одновременно.

Но имплементация содержит ошибку, потому что создаёт возможность дедлока при одновременно выполнении `A->B` и `B->A`, т.е. один поток заблокирует А, другой B, и они будут ждать друг друга.

Чтобы исправить это, надо всегда блокировки накладывать в одном и том же порядке. В данном случае можно было бы упорядочить по номеру счёта

```
public void transfer(Account source, Account target, double amount) {
    Object firstLock,secondLock;
    if (source.getAccNum() < target.getAccNum()) {
       firstLock= sourceLock;
       secondLock= targetLock;
    } else {
       firstLock= targetLock;
       secondLock= sourceLock;
    }
    synchronized (firstLock) {
        synchronized (secondLock) {
            source.setBalance(source.getBalance() - amount);
            target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь не важно направление перевода (`A->B` или `B->A`), блокировки всегда будут накладываться в одном порядке `A,B` и дедлок не возникнет.

Comment: Отличная идея  - сортировать номера, чтобы lock'и захватывались по порядку!